# Issue: CSV file upload works only when "View page source" is done

Tags: plugins, uploads, csv

I ma having little wired issue while uploading the csv file. Here the code I have. The actual site is developed in wordpress. This is to show the issue and same issue happens in the plugin developed.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="uploadactionval" value="test">
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<input type="submit" name="myfilesubbtn" value="Import From CSV">
</p>
```

```
        if(isset($_POST['myfilesubbtn']) && isset($_POST['uploadactionval']))
        {
            $file_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['myfile']['name']);              
            if ( $file_parts['extension'] == "csv" )
            { 
               $message = uploadCSV($_FILES);
               echo "<p><b>$message</b></p>"; die;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p><b>Please upload the CSV file only!</p>";
            }

        }


        function uploadCSV($files)
        {
            $target_file = '';
            $target_file = '/var/www/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/uploads/csv/' . basename($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
            if (move_uploaded_file($files["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

?> 
This code uploads the csv file in respective folder and works perfectly fine when run in the local server. I have AWS server. When the csv is uploaded with URL "www.mysite.com/csvupload.php", the file is not uploaded. But then I do "Page view source" the page shows as below:

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
>   will repeat any action this page previously performed.

Then I reload the page and the file is uploaded in the respective folder.

This is something strange happening to me. Is there something that I have missed here and I am not aware of (Please note this is perfectly working fine on the local server)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how about if you change `function uploadCSV($files)` to be `function uploadCSV($_FILES)`?

Comment: Thanks @Jevuska for the response. I decreased size of the csv file less than 10M and that works fine. Thinking that this is the file size issue, upload_max_filesize has been increased from 10M to 30M but no luck  yet. I am still working to check reason behind this.

Comment: oh sorry, I don't make attention that you have variable $files inside. where you change upload_max_filesize?

Comment: I figured out the issue. As the file gets uploaded even file size being more than 10M I didn't think that it was the issue of file size. So now, what I did is changed post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 30M and it resolved my issue. Anyway thank you @Jevuska